# Illegal offset type in my php class function

Tags: php

I am getting illegal offset error in one of my function.

Here is the code

```
public function translate($str, $namespace = '') {
        $namespace = $this->getNamespace($namespace);

        $this->load($namespace);

        $lang = $this->getLang();
        $data = $this->data[$namespace];

        $key = md5($str);

        if (isset($data[$lang][$key])) {
            return $data[$lang][$key];
        }

        $default = $this->getDefaultLang();

        if ($lang == $default) {
            if ($this->getSaveOnMissing()) {
                $save = array(
                    'namespace' => $namespace,
                    'lang' => $lang,
                    'trans_key' => $key,
                    'trans_val' => $str
                );

                $sql = $GLOBALS['db']->strInsert('translate', $save);
                if ($GLOBALS['db']->SQL_query($sql)) {
                    $this->data[$namespace][$lang][$key] = $str;
                }
            }

            return $str;
        } elseif (isset($data[$default][$key])) {
            
            return $data[$default][$key];
        }

        return $str;
    }
```

In this line I am getting this error

```
elseif (isset($data[$default][$key]))
```

Comment: Please, show exact error message and how do you call your function.

Comment: What does `var_dump($data[$default])` show?

Comment: Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type ([php.net arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php))

Comment: @freeek PHP Warning:  Illegal offset type in .......... on line 90 this is it

Comment: What are `$lang` and `$default`? Are they maybe some type of object?

Answer (score -1):

So there are 3 levels of your value

1. $data
2. $default
3. $key

You can check by three levels first if they are all returning something

```
elseif(isset($data, $data[$default], $data[$default][$key])
```

Comment: There is no actual need for this. A single `isset` with the deepest level will fail no matter which level isn't set. See [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/eHeXe).